# Weekly Average Amount over a month with window function in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, moving-average, partition-by

PySpark dataframe with following columns:

```
'step', 'type', 'amount', 'Payee_Account', 'Old_Bal_Orig', 'New_Bal_Orig', 'Beneficiary_Account','Old_Bal_Dest', 'New_Bal_Dest', 'day_of_month', 'day_of_week'
```

where step is the timestamp in Hour starting from 1.

[image: dataframe]

Following code will calculate a monthly average for each beneficiary. But we need weekly average over a month. That is, range is the month and the averaging period is week.

[image: example]

```
df = df.withColumn("Freq_Benef_Acc", F.avg('amount').over(Window.partitionBy("Beneficiary_Account").orderBy("day_of_month").rangeBetween(-30, Window.currentRow)) )
```

Comment: can you specify the approaches you tried?

Comment: `df = df.withColumn("Freq_Benef_Acc", F.avg('amount').over(Window.partitionBy("Beneficiary_Account", "day_of_month").orderBy("day_of_week").rangeBetween(-7, Window.currentRow)) )`

Comment: @SomeshwarKale I tried the code approach that I have mentioned above. But did not get the desired result.

Comment: please avoid adding images. Also please take sample data and put the expected result with spark dataframe